# Change Sequence to Choice

Tags: xml, schema, xsd

In my Schema File I defined a *Group* with a *Sequence* of possible *Elements*.

```
<group name="argumentGroup">
    <sequence>
        <element name="foo" type="double" />
        <element name="bar" type="string" />
        <element name="baz" type="integer" />
    </sequence> 
</group>
```

I then reference this *Group* like this:

```
<element name="arguments">
    <complexType>
        <group ref="my:argumentGroup"/>
    </complexType>
</element>
```

Is it possible to reference the *Group* at some other point but restrict it so it's a *Choice* instead of a *Sequence*. The position where I want to reuse it would only allow one of the *Elements* within.

```
<element name="argument" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
    <complexType>
        <group name="my:argumentGroup">
            <! -- Somehow change argumentGroup sequence to choice here -->
        </group>
    <complexType>
</element>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you will need to define a different group.

Answer (score 2):

No. You cannot do this with groups. To get this type of reusability, use a complex type instead of a group to define the sequence of elements (foo, bar, baz).

Assign this complex type to an element in your schema using restriction. However, you would need the base complex type to use the choice element.

It seems that, using restriction, you can update the choice element to be a sequence in the restriction. However, if the base complex type is defined using a sequence, then updating the restricted element to a choice will cause the schema to fail validation.

Comment: Thanks. I went with a different group. Was more straightforward to implement.

Comment: Wouldn't restricting the old type 1) create a choice of sequences and/or 2) require typing the xs:element tags again so there is wouldn't be benefit from the reuse?

Comment: @jasso - I updated my response for accuracy. The problem being that you can restrict a choice to be a sequence, but you can't restrict a sequence to be a choice.